# Adding widget into order page wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

How can Ι add widgets in orders page of woocomerce? Is it even possible?

I'm surfinγ all over the internet ant Ι can't find anything. I want to add widget in this are Ι marked red. Maybe i should edit woocomerce files or something?

Or maybe should Ι register widget to that page or something with `register_widget` codes:

[image]

If there is any psosiblity please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do You try WooSidebars plugin ?
https://wordpress.org/plugins/woosidebars/

"WooSidebars adds functionality to display different widgets in a sidebar, according to a context (for example, a specific page or a category)."